# Should I learn C++ before I advance too much further in Python?

Tags: python, c++

First, to give you a slight bit of background on me:

Perl is technically the first language I was introduced to, but I quickly migrated to Python when I found how clean and easy it is to write.  I've now been working in Python for about 8 months, and I feel that I'm reaching an 'intermediate' stage.  I have the language syntax, data-structures, and memory usage principles pretty much down, and now I'm starting to get into things such as algorithmic design and some of the slightly deeper topics like function closures.

I'm teaching myself C++ on the side, and I'll be honest, it feels tedious and extremely obtuse to me.  It might be how new I am too it still, but I have to force myself to practice C++ whereas I can barely get enough coding in Python.  I've heard people say it's good to learn to give you a baseline knowledge about computers and memory management, so my question is if I should "catch-up" in C++ to where I'm at in Python before continuing?  I think the convenience of Python is making it hard to learn C++ as a second language.

Comment: Do what you enjoy most!

Comment: Subjective questions like this are off-topic here, sorry. Stack Overflow isn't a chat or forum. Though there are chat rooms offered, where you may want to discuss such stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you should try to fully master one language before advancing to another. If you juggle too many at the same time you will just mix up their syntax and spend a lot of time becoming a jack of all trade and a master of non.

Comment: Working 8 months on a language is a considerable amount of time to not mix it up with another though. I agree with you generally, but in this certain Python or C++ question i believe that advancing in C++ provides a better learning curve than advancing in Python. Don't get me wrong i really like Python and i believe its the best language to make things quick and in a secure way, i just believe its not a language worth focusing when your main goal is to learn more about the way computers work in general.

Comment: @uhexos -  This is an opinion. It's not an answer.

Comment: @david wasnt that what he asked for

Comment: @kostas 8 months is actually considerable, but it seemed like he is just testing out every language he can get his hands on which is fine for now but sooner or later the confusions would begin to set in. At least that's what would happen to me.

Comment: @uhexos The issue is that the OP asked an off-topic question. There are no right answers to this, only opinions (which is why the question has already been closed). Your answer, while marked as accepted by the OP, is no more "correct" than an answer stating the exact opposite of yours. This is why it's best not to post as you have.

Comment: @david i see where you were coming from now